# Maximum of a utility function

Tags: derivatives, related-rates

I was practising some related rates problems and I came across this particularly difficult question. The question goes like this:

Suppose Peyam's utility function is given by:

$U(\theta)=\frac{\mu C}{\mu\sin(\theta)\;+\;\cos(\theta)}$

where *C* is a universal cake-constant and $\mu$ is the intensity of happiness.

**Note:** Think of $\theta$ here as the time of the year. So $\theta=0$ corresponds to the beginning of January 1st, and $\theta=2\pi$ corresponds to the end of December 31st.

Show that Peyam is happiest precisely when $\tan(\theta)=\mu$.

I believe what is being asked for is the value of the maximum value of $\mu$, which should be equal to $\tan(\theta)$

I tried by making $\mu$ the subject, and ended up with

$\mu=\frac{U(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{C-U(\theta)\sin(\theta)}$

I'm guessing the next thing to do is to differentiate, but I'm not exactly sure how to differentiate $U(\theta)$. Do I substitute back in the original equation for $U(\theta)$? How can I move on from here?

Comment: This would be an extremization problem, rather than a related-rates calculation: for what value(s) of $ \ \theta \ $ is the derivative of $ \ U \ $ equal to zero? As it stands,  $ \ \mu \ $ can be "canceled out" from this ratio.  _Is it_ a constant?  Is it supposed to be in _all_ of the terms in _both_ the numerator and denominator?

Comment: You're new so I hope you'll learn this:  Always write an *INFORMATIVE* title... one that relates to the specifics of your problem.

Comment: You should also show what you've tried yourself on this problem; otherwise, this post will likely be closed.  This is not an "answers-on-request" site.

Comment: @boojum sorry I added an extra mu in the denominator, I've made an edit now

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, thanks for understanding, I only recently discovered stack exchange. I hear the guidelines on posts here are pretty strict. What should the title look like? I'd appreciate it if you could help so I don't make this mistake in the future

Comment: @boojum wouldn't that give you the maximum for U(θ)? I believe they were asking the max value for μ

Answer (score 1):

It looks like we want to treat the "utility" as a *number* $ \ 0 \ < \ U \ < \ 1 \ $ in order to keep the ratio defined "everywhere". [Graph the curve $ \ \frac{y}{y·\sin(x) \ + \ \cos(x)}   $ equal to a constant and vary the constant's  value  to see this.]  There is then a "family" of such utility functions which have maxima in the specified interval for $ \ \theta \ . $

Since $ \ \mu \ $ is  a variable in addition to $ \ \theta \ , \ $ it will help to write the relation as
$$ U·(\mu \sin \theta \ + \ \cos \theta) \ \  = \ \ \mu · C \ \ , $$

which we would differentiate implicitly with respect to $ \ \theta \ \ , $ thus
$$ \frac{d}{d \theta} \ [ \ U · (\mu · \sin \theta \ + \  \cos \theta)  \ ] \ \  = \ \ \frac{d}{d \theta} \ [ \ \mu · C \ ]    $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ U · \left( \frac{d \mu}{d \theta} · \sin \theta \ + \mu·\cos \theta \ - \  \sin \theta \right) \ \ = \  \ C  ·  \frac{d \mu}{d \theta}  $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \   \frac{d \mu}{d \theta} · (C \ - \ U · \sin \theta) \ \ = \ \ U ·  (  \mu·\cos \theta \ - \  \sin \theta  ) \ \ . $$

Since we want the maximal value for $ \ \mu \  $ in any particular utility function, we would set $ \  \frac{d \mu}{d \theta} \ = \ 0 \ \ $ and the result for $ \ \mu \ $ follows.  So this is sort of a "related-rates" problem...

Answer (score 0):

No need to make $\mu$ a subject.

You take derivative of the utility function and equate to zero:
$$U'(\theta)=\left[\frac{\mu C}{\mu\sin(\theta)\;+\;\cos(\theta)}\right]'=-\frac{\mu C\cdot [\mu \cos(\theta)-\sin(\theta)]}{\mu \sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta)}=0 $$
Can you finish it yourself?